# cakephp3 Pages Controller Viewing a Plugin Page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Is it necessary to to create a copy of the `PagesController.php` everytime i make a plugin that has a page that i want to view?

Is it possable to use just one pages controller?

EG a plugin called **blah**, has a page in the `src/Template/pages` folder called;

```
demo.ctp
```

To view this i need to copy the `PagesController.php` to my plugin;

**myapp/plugins/blah/src/Controller/**

To view it;

> http://localhost/myapp/blah/pages/display/demo

Is this correct usage of the controller?